# ¿Como hacer un pull sin sobreescribir los archivos locales?

Tags: git-pull

Sin darme cuenta estaba trabajando en la rama develop del proyecto y no en la mía, entonces cuando hago un git pull de esa rama (develop) me aparece un error diciendome que serán sobreescritos algunos archivos locales al fusionar, y quisiera conservalos para posteriormente hacer un merge con mi rama local y trabajar normalmente.El mensaje de error es el siguiente:

```
error: Los cambios locales de los siguientes archivos serán sobrescritos al fusionar:
        app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
        app/models/vehicle.rb
        config/environments/development.rb
Por favor, confirma tus cambios o aguárdalos antes de fusionar.
Abortando
```

Comment: Intenta hacer `stash` de tus cambios, luego `pull` y luego aplicas de nuevo el stash

Comment: Perfecto, con eso resolví. Gracias

Comment: Con mucho gusto